# Invalid property 'jobParameters' of bean class StepContext: Bean property 'jobParameters' is not readable or has an invalid getter method

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

Sometimes, while my batch is running, trying to get `JobParameters` with this simple code

```
<bean id="codiceParametroMaxDurataJob" class="java.lang.String"
    scope="step">
    <constructor-arg
        value="#{jobParameters['job'].concat('_DURATA_MASSIMA_ESECUZIONE')}">
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

I get the following exception

> Encountered an error executing the step
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.stepCheck' defined in class path
>   resource [StampeBatchDataLayer.xml]: Initialization of bean failed;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression
>   parsing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException:
>   EL1029E:(pos 55): A problem occurred when trying to execute method
>   'checkParametro' on object of type 'java.lang.Class': 'Problem
>   invoking method: public static java.lang.String
>   com.arca.stampebatch.datalayer.cache.CheckParametri.checkParametro(java.util.List,java.lang.String)
>   throws com.arca.danni.utils.exception.SpringBatchStopException'
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:332)
>         at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:150)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:328)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>         at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:33)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:182)
>         at $Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
>         at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:386)
>         at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
>         at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:264)
>         at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:76)
>         at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:367)
>         at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:214)
>         at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:143)
>         at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:250)
>         at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
>         at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135)
>         at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
>         at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
>         at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
>         at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
>         at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
>         at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:281)
>         at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
>         at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
>         at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:114)
>         at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:349)
>         at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:574)
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression
>   parsing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException:
>   EL1029E:(pos 55): A problem occurred when trying to execute method
>   'checkParametro' on object of type 'java.lang.Class': 'Problem
>   invoking method: public static java.lang.String
>   com.arca.stampebatch.datalayer.cache.CheckParametri.checkParametro(java.util.List,java.lang.String)
>   throws com.arca.danni.utils.exception.SpringBatchStopException'
>         at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:142)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1299)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.evaluate(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:210)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:182)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>         ... 29 more
>       Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException:
>   EL1029E:(pos 55): A problem occurred when trying to execute method
>   'checkParametro' on object of type 'java.lang.Class': 'Problem
>   invoking method: public static java.lang.String
>   com.arca.stampebatch.datalayer.cache.CheckParametri.checkParametro(java.util.List,java.lang.String)
>   throws com.arca.danni.utils.exception.SpringBatchStopException'
>         at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:114)
>         at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:57)
>         at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:93)
>         at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:88)
>         at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:139)
>         ... 35 more
>       Caused by: org.springframework.expression.AccessException: Problem invoking method: public static java.lang.String
>   com.arca.stampebatch.datalayer.cache.CheckParametri.checkParametro(java.util.List,java.lang.String)
>   throws com.arca.danni.utils.exception.SpringBatchStopException
>         at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:73)
>         at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:109)
>         ... 39 more
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression
>   parsing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'jobParameters' of bean class
>   [org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContext]: Bean
>   property 'jobParameters' is not readable or has an invalid getter
>   method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of
>   the setter?
>         at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:142)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1299)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.evaluate(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:210)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:182)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:630)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:332)
>         at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:150)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:328)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>         at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:33)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:182)
>         at $Proxy19.toString(Unknown Source)
>         at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeToString(ObjectUtils.java:610)
>         at org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException.(ConversionFailedException.java:46)
>         at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41)
>         at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:171)
>         at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardTypeConverter.convertValue(StandardTypeConverter.java:66)
>         at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectionHelper.convertArguments(ReflectionHelper.java:281)
>         at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:61)
>         ... 40 more
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'jobParameters' of bean class
>   [org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContext]: Bean
>   property 'jobParameters' is not readable or has an invalid getter
>   method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of
>   the setter?
>         at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:729)
>         at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:721)
>         at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.resolveContextualObject(StepScope.java:131)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext.containsObject(BeanExpressionContext.java:51)
>         at org.springframework.context.expression.BeanExpressionContextAccessor.canRead(BeanExpressionContextAccessor.java:36)
>         at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:190)
>         at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:72)
>         at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:52)
>         at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:93)
>         at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:88)
>         at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:139)
>         ... 63 more

When the exception is thrown, I try to relaunch the batch and the result is OK.

Why, on a second run and immediately after the first, is the exception not thrown?

I'm using Spring Batch 2.1.8.RELEASE and IBM JDK 1.7

How can I resolve the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: try to log `jobParameters['job'].concat('_DURATA_MASSIMA_ESECUZIONE')` before executing to check if there is a naming issue.

Comment: How can I log `jobParameters['job'].concat('_DURATA_MASSIMA_ESECUZIONE')` in my spring batch XML configuration?